How to convert vimscript to Neovim Lua with help of spliting line key and function?
How to convert this vimscript code into Lazyvim Lua code?
 function! BreakHere()
        s/^\(\s*\)\(.\{-}\)\(\s*\)\(\%#\)\(\s*\)\(.*\)/\1\2\r\1\4\6
        call histdel("/", -1)
    endfunction

nnoremap K :<C-u>call BreakHere()<CR>


Why do you need to convert it?

Do you still have something open in your question? How can we help you further? Otherwise maybe could you accept one of the solutions using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

the idea splitting line help  of keymap capital k (shift + k), opposite of capital j (joining line) works well vimscript help above vim code. but not in neovim lua (Lazyvim). is possible ??

I would do:
vim.keymap.set('n', 'K', function()
  vim.cmd([[s/^\(\s*\)\(.\{-}\)\(\s*\)\(\%#\)\(\s*\)\(.*\)/\1\2\r\1\4\6]])
  vim.fn.histdel('/', -1)
end, {})

Remark:

To map keys you can use the vim.keymap.set api
[[...]] is the Lua notation for raw string (the equivalent of r".." string in Python).
To access the Vim builtin function you can use the vim.fn collection

Remark: for LazyVim the mapping code standard location is ~/.config/nvim/lua/config/keymaps.lua on Linux and ~/AppData/Local/nvim/lua/config/keymaps.lua on Windows.
Remark: Here is a variation of the expression that avoid breaking within the words:
vim.keymap.set('n', 'K', function()
  vim.cmd([[s/\v^(\s*)(.{-})(>\s*)(\S*%#)(\s*)(.*)/\1\2\r\1\4\6]])
  vim.fn.histdel('/', -1)
end, {})

Remark: If autoindent is set you could also do approximate with:
vim.keymap.set('n', 'K', 'EBi<CR><Esc>EB', {})


thank help convert lua script with zero error.  But it doesn't work well,  The idea is Splitting line capital k (shift+k) opposite of capital J (joining line),  In vim script work quiet well. `function! BreakHere()
s/^(\s*)(.{-})(\s*)(%#)(\s*)(.*)/\1\2\r\1\4\6
call histdel("/", -1)
endfunction
nnoremap K :call BreakHere()`

Could you give us an example that works with the Vim Substitution and not with the mapping? It would help us reproducing the problem :-)
